# TypeScript: Argument of type is not assignable

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongoose

TypeScript newbie here migrating an existing project. We have Mongoose models, which look similar to the following snippet and use the `discriminatorKey` property:

```
const task = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  notes: {
    type: String
  }
}, {
  discriminatorKey: 'type',
  toObject: {
    virtuals: true
  },
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true
  }
});
```

This gives me the following error during compilation:

```
src/models/task.ts(12,3): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ discriminatorKey: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SchemaOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'discriminatorKey' does not exist in type 'SchemaOptions'.
```

I'm using these @types definition, which seems to be the most recent one:

```
"@types/mongoose": "^4.7.8"
```

I understand, that the type definitions do not specify the `discriminatorKey` (this is obviously visible when looking at `node_modules/@types/mongoose/index.d.ts`), but I do not understand (a) why (oversight? different version? other reason?), (b) how can I circumvent this error?

(c) Bonus question: The versioning strategy of the `@types` definitions is still unclear to me. I would assume, that the type definitions should match the version of the actual library, however, often there does not seem to be a matching version -- e.g. we're using `express` version. 4.13.4, but there is no matching `@types/express` version available. What's the best practice to follow in this case?

Comment: Literals are subject to *Excess Property Checks*. Search for the term on this page: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a bit late, but I have just come across the same issue. I'm using `@types/mongoose` `4.7.12` and it hasn't been updated yet.

As a temporal solutions, when you come across this kind of issues, you have two options:

**Cast the whole problematic object to `any`**

As you are defining the options inline, you can cast them to [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any):

```
const task: mongoose.Schema = new mongoose.Schema({ ... }, {
    discriminatorKey: 'type',

    ...
} as any);
```

or

```
const task: mongoose.Schema = new mongoose.Schema({ ... }, <any> {
    discriminatorKey: 'type',

    ...
});
```

The downside of this approach is that now type checking for that [`SchemaOptions`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mongoose/index.d.ts) object will be disabled for all the properties, so if you make a typo in, let's say, `toJSON`, and type `toJSNO` instead, `TypeScript` will not warn you.

**Cast the problematic object to `any` just in the statement that uses unknown properties**

A different approach to keep type checking working for the known properties but disable it for the *yet* unknown ones is to define that options object before with the known properties and add the unknown ones later casting them to `any`:

```
const options: mongoose.SchemaOptions = {
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
};

(options as any).discriminatorKey = 'type';

// or (<any> options).discriminatorKey = 'type';

const task = new mongoose.Schema({ ... }, options);
```

**Side note: Please, contribute!**

If you find any similar issue in this package or in any other in the future, this is a really easy and minimal change that you can fix and PR to [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped). Actually, for something like this you don't even need to clone the repo, I was able to do it just by using the edit button in GitHub.

Here's the PR: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/16598, once it is merged, just update to the most recent version.

Comment: Thank you! I've also progressed my skills in the meantime, but still that's a really nice write-up of all available options! And of course many thanks for improving the typings!

Comment: still facing this with.. "@types/mongoose": "^5.5.8"